# How elasticsearch to synch mapping between all nodes？

Tags: elasticsearch

When i create or update a mapping on one node,How `es` to synch mapping?

synchronized or asynchronous？

When synching a mapping,`es` can index data at that time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, when you do an `update` or a `create` the mapping is pretty much synchronized. Obviously you could create an index using the `mapping` API as well! FYI the master node is the only node in a cluster that can make changes to the cluster state. The master node processes one cluster state update at a time, applies the required changes and publishes the updated cluster state to all the other nodes in the cluster.

You could have a look at [this](https://www.elastic.co/blog/great-mapping-refactoring), for a better explanation on synchronization. Hope it helps!